# how to clear all imges if maxium user uploaded limit is reached?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to clear all images those are uploaded if maximum upload limit is reached.If i upload images using browse button it shows all the images i have uploaded.But what i am trying to achieve is that if i upload more then 4 photo then it should either reset the all uploaded photo or shouldn't allow user to load more then 4 photo at first place.In my case if I am  more then 4 photoes.

My Html.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-4 control-label text_left">Upload Image(s)</label>
   <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div>
         <input type="file" id="files" name="media" multiple accept="image/*" />
         <output id="list"></output>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

my scripts..

```
$(function(){
    $('#files').change(function(){
       var $fileUpload = $("input[type='file']");
       if (parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length)>4){
           alert("You can only upload a maximum of 4 files");
           ("#files").replaceWith($("#files").val('').clone(true));
           ("#files")[0].value = "";
       }
    });
});
```

Please help me.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "clear all images"?

Comment: the problem is it is not reseting the upload though it shows the pop that u can olny upload 4 images only but it is not clearing the images

Comment: What do you mean by "clearing the images"? Note, `parseInt()` call is not necessary.

Comment: by clear all images is when i upload the images it shows all the images like i have uploaded....now i want to clear it if user has uploaded more then 4 images..and reset it to none

Comment: `FileList` is read only. It is not possible to set or delete items from `.files` property of `<input type="file">` element which represents `FileList` object. Are you trying to limit upload to server to only four images? Note, missing `$` or `jQuery` before `("#files")`

Comment: yes sir i am trying to limit the user to 4 images.

Comment: You'll need the server to make this check. With a client-only check (JavaScript) a user can just refresh the page and upload more. They can also clear cookies and local Storage, or use a different browser all together. You need a server-sided solution, and have users identified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileList` is read only. It is not possible to set or delete items from `.files` property of `<input type="file">` element which represents `FileList` object. `parseInt()` call is not necessary, `.files.length` returns an integer.

If you are trying to limit upload to four user selected files you can iterate `.files`, append only first four files to `FormData` object, then post `FormData` to server.

```js
var limit = 4;

$(":file").on("change", function() {
    var n = 0;
    var fd = new FormData();
    for (let file of this.files) {
      fd.append("file" + n++, file);
      if (n === limit) break;
    }
    console.log(Array.from(fd.keys()).length);
    for (let [key, prop] of fd.entries()) {
      console.log(key, prop)
    }
    // $.post("/path/to/server", fd)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-4 control-label text_left">Upload Image(s)</label>
   <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div>
         <input type="file" id="files" name="media" multiple accept="image/*" />
         <output id="list"></output>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively

```
if (this.files.length > 4) {
  // do nothing
} else {
  // do stuff with files
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `replaceWith`. A simple `.val("")` will clear the `file input`.

```js
$("#upl").on("change", function() {
  if ($("#upl").get(0).files.length > 4) {
    alert("You cant upload more than 4 files.");
    $("#upl").val("");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="upl" multiple/>
```

Comment: it is still showing the uploaded image.I want to restrict the user to upload only 4 images and if he uploaded more than 4 photo it shouldn't select the image at the first place

Comment: @A.Waqas _"I want to restrict the user to upload only 4 images and if he uploaded more than 4 photo it shouldn't select the image at the first place"_ You cannot programmatically "restrict" a user from selecting more than an arbitrary number of files where `multiple` attribute is set at `<input type="file">` element. The files have already been selected when `change` event is dispatched. You can filter the files that should or should not uploaded to server after user selects files at `change` event handler.

Comment: @A.Waqas if you try to select more than 4 files in the snippet, you'll see that it will not allow the user to do it and clear the input. If you are trying to check for images user uploaded to server-side before, that is a whole different matter and your question doesn't reflect any server-side info.

Comment: @Ozan _"if you try to select more than 4 files in the snippet, you'll see that it will not allow the user to do it"_ Note, the files would have already been selected by user when `change` event is dispatched. `change` event is dispatched at `<input type="file">` element after user has selected files from user filesystem.

Comment: @guest271314, in OP's question the logic was inside `change event handler`, and javascript can not interfere with file selection popup anyways; so I didn't even consider they'd be trying to prevent the selection in the system popup.

Comment: @Ozan The previous comment was regarding _"will not allow the user to do it"_ portion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43361387/how-to-clear-all-imges-if-maxium-user-uploaded-limit-is-reached/43361820#comment73785706_43361589 , where the files were already selected. Yes, it appears OP is attempting to restrict user from selecting more than N files, which is not possible; at least not using `multiple` attribute approach alone.